# Audio file not playing with userscript in tampermoney

Tags: javascript, audio, tampermonkey

I'm trying to use user script through Tampermonkey to play an audio file, but for some reason I'm getting this error in the console when I tried to run the code and the audio file isn't playing:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

[https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes%22).

What does that mean, and how do I fix it?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        play audio
// @namespace   John Galt
// @description Basic Google Hello
// @match       *^https://www.google.com/$*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

// alert("hello");
const newAudio = new Audio("someaudio");
newAudio.play();
```

Comment: It's right there in the article you linked:  Have the victim of your userscript set the `AutoplayWhitelist` on his machine.

Answer (score 2):

Users can disable [Chrome's autoplay policy](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) by going to:

```
chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy
```

From this page, you can set the Chrome flag "**Autoplay Policy**" to "**No user gesture is required**".

Alternatively, you can use Chrome enterprise policies to change the autoplay behavior:

- [`AutoplayAllowed`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AutoplayAllowed) controls whether autoplay is allowed or not.
- [`AutoplayAllowlist`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AutoplayAllowlist) allows you to specify an allowlist of URL patterns where autoplay will always be enabled.

Comment: Sadly that flag does not exist anymore!

Answer (score 1):

## solution for windows

1. open regedit
2. navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoplayAllowlist` and create all non existing keys
3. create a text value named `1` and add your url where playback should be allowed. for a tampermonkey script this must be the site where your script runs. lets take google for example `https://www.google.com`
4. if your script runs on multiple URL, add further entries like `2`=`https://www.stackoverflow.com`, `3`=`https://en.wikipedia.org`
5. close chrome and start chrome again. should not be required (according to the linked document from the other question), but for me it only worked after restarting chrome.

source: links provided by grant miller from 2018-08-18

Answer (score 0):

If the Chrome `autoplay-policy` flag is not visible in the `chrome://flags` screen, use this procedure instead:

Start Chrome using this command line flag:

`chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`

#### More information:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#developer-switches